# "How many tables in the picture? " or "How many tables ARE in the picture?"

Tags: grammar, questions

Which one of the two sentences below is right?

- *How many tables in the picture?*
- *How many tables ARE in the picture?*

Comment: How many tables are in the picture.

Comment: It depends totally on the context. In the UK, "How many tables are there in the picture?" would be most idiomatic, while many in the US would use the deleted form "How many tables are in the picture?" Neither of these is in any way unacceptable. But "How many tables in the picture?" while not being a complete syntactic sentence (lacking a finite verb) still gets a complete idea across, and could be used in informal conversation / as one of a series of similar questions in a childrens book (no apostrophe my choice), etc. It depends on which 'right' we're talking about.